# Exporting After Effects animation to SVG with SMIL

Tags: svg, animation, adobe-after-effects

I'm curious if there's a way to export animations from Adobe After Effects to SVG containing [SMIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronized_Multimedia_Integration_Language#SMIL+SVG)

I'm currently using the tool Bodymovin, but that's limited to only exporting bloated JSON files and is depended on external scripts.

Answer (score 1):

It is not likely that this tool exists, i wont say "no", but unlikely. If it would, then the community would be aware of it or that it would be very proprietary which wouldn't help you much anyway. SMIL already on its way out of circulation (chrome is dropping support) so its very unlikely that somebody still has anything like this in works.

> But that's limited to only exporting bloated JSON files and is depended on external scripts

Well, you can try to make a less unbloated version*. If you limit yourself to small subset you should be done in no time. Off course the SMIL environment is more restrictive but you can always bake the keyframes to a bunch of linear moves - Bodymovin devs just decided to do that in javascript instead because they probably felt that was less bloated.

* Its not really hard but rather time consuming